# replace a column with another column when column is null in SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my dummy Schema in MYSQL:
**A column**: which is a nullable string 
**B column**: which is a string but its not null 

[image]

I only want to select **A** columns but when facing a null, I want it to be replaced with the **B** column.
How can I do that?

this is my desired output
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `coalesce()`:

```
select coalesce(a, b) as a
from t;
```

Answer (score 3):

coalesce() or

```
SELECT CASE WHEN A IS NOT NULL THEN A ELSE B END AS value FROM tablename;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use `ifnull`, the sound of which makes it easy to remember. Note that it only works for 2 columns/values

```
select ifnull(a, b) as a
from t;
```